# BufferOverFlowException when puting vertices into VertexBuffer

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I'm trying to draw a circle using OpenGL. I've got the following code:

```
int numberOfVertices = 100;
float[][] vertices = new float[numberOfVertices][2];
private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer; // Buffer for vertex-array

public Circle(){    
    setUpVertices(1.0f);
    // Setup vertex-array buffer. Vertices in float. A float has 4 bytes
    ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
    vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()); // Use native byte order
    vertexBuffer = vbb.asFloatBuffer(); // Convert byte buffer to float

    //Loop through the vertices and put them in the vertexbuffer
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfVertices; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= 1; j++) {
            System.out.println("x,y: " + vertices[i][j] + " i,j: (" + i + "," + j + ")");
            vertexBuffer.put(vertices[i][j]); // Copy data into buffer
        }
    }
    vertexBuffer.position(0); // Rewind
}
```

setUpVertices:

```
private void setUpVertices(float radius) {
    float theta = (float) (2 * Math.PI / (numberOfVertices - 1));
    float c = (float) Math.cos(theta);
    float s = (float) Math.sin(theta);
    float x = radius;
    float y = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfVertices; i++) {
        vertices[i][0] = x;
        vertices[i][1] = y;
        //indices[ii] = (byte) ii;
        float t = x;
        x = c * x - s * y;
        y = s * t + c * y;
    }
}
```

stacktrace:

```
03-28 08:09:08.689: E/AndroidRuntime(4776): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-28 08:09:08.689: E/AndroidRuntime(4776): Process: se.saxman.oj, PID: 4776
03-28 08:09:08.689: E/AndroidRuntime(4776): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{se.saxman.oj/se.saxman.oj.Graphics.OJGLActivity}: java.nio.BufferOverflowException
03-28 08:09:08.689: E/AndroidRuntime(4776):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
03-28 08:09:08.689: E/AndroidRuntime(4776):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
03-28 08:09:08.689: E/AndroidRuntime(4776):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
03-28 08:09:08.689: E/AndroidRuntime(4776):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
03-28 08:09:08.689: E/AndroidRuntime(4776):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-28 08:09:08.689: E/AndroidRuntime(4776):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-28 08:09:08.689: E/AndroidRuntime(4776):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-28 08:09:08.689: E/AndroidRuntime(4776):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-28 08:09:08.689: E/AndroidRuntime(4776):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-28 08:09:08.689: E/AndroidRuntime(4776):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-28 08:09:08.689: E/AndroidRuntime(4776):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-28 08:09:08.689: E/AndroidRuntime(4776):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-28 08:09:08.689: E/AndroidRuntime(4776): Caused by: java.nio.BufferOverflowException
03-28 08:09:08.689: E/AndroidRuntime(4776):     at java.nio.ByteBufferAsFloatBuffer.put(ByteBufferAsFloatBuffer.java:142)
03-28 08:09:08.689: E/AndroidRuntime(4776):     at se.saxman.oj.Graphics.Circle.<init>(Circle.java:26)
03-28 08:09:08.689: E/AndroidRuntime(4776):     at se.saxman.oj.Graphics.OJGLRenderer.<init>(OJGLRenderer.java:33)
03-28 08:09:08.689: E/AndroidRuntime(4776):     at se.saxman.oj.Graphics.OJGLActivity.onCreate(OJGLActivity.java:16)
03-28 08:09:08.689: E/AndroidRuntime(4776):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
03-28 08:09:08.689: E/AndroidRuntime(4776):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
03-28 08:09:08.689: E/AndroidRuntime(4776):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
03-28 08:09:08.689: E/AndroidRuntime(4776):     ... 11 more
```

Why can't i "put all of them" into the VB? I've printed them out and only come to i = 50 before it crashes. Removing the for( int j = 0; j <= 1; j++) almost makes it work, but doesn't seem right. Anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: what is the relation between `vertices.length` and `numberOfVertices`, the first should be twice the second to stay within bounds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you didn't allocate enough space for the vertices:

```
//2 float coordinates per vertex and 4 bytes per float
ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(numberOfVertices * 2 * 4);
```

Comment: It worked, now I just have to make it smoother. For some reason it doesn't matter if I use 25 or 100 as numberOfVertices. Maybe there is a limit, although it doesn't get completely smooth :/

Answer (score 0):

Use this method:

```
floatBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertexData.length * 4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer().put(vertexData);
```

whit any float[] array as vertexData. It will take care of the size needed and also fix the byte ordering.

Comment: I have a float[][] (not necessary?) so it doesn't work. Sorry that I didn't say that, I've added it to the question. And is that method supposed to replace all the code (except for setUpVertices()) in the constructor?